# Palindrom checker,wrong output

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve Problem 4 -Project Euler and I am stucked. So I need a little help with my code. Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrom(int number, int revrse) {
    char str1[6];
    char str2[6];

    sprintf(str1, "%d", number);
    sprintf(str2, "%d", revrse);

    return strcmp(str1, str2);
}

int main(void) {
    int number, revrse;
    int i, j, temp;
    int maks;

    for(i=999;i>99;i--)
        for(j=999;j>99;j--) {
            temp = number = i*j;
            while (temp != 0) {
                revrse = revrse * 10;
                revrse = revrse + temp%10;
                temp = temp/10;
            }
            if(is_palindrom(number, revrse)==0 && number > maks)
                maks = number;
        }
    printf("%d",maks);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `char str1[7];char str2[7];`...`int maks=0;`...`revrse = 0;while(temp != 0){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the reversed form of your number properly, you need to first set an initial value for `revrse` of 0 for each iteration of your loop, otherwise the behavior is undefined.  It also helps to set an initial value for `maks` to compare against.  Finally, why use a function to check for palindromes when you can just check for equality between your number and its reverse?

```
int main()
{
    int number;
    int i,j,temp;
    int maks = -1;
    int revrse;

    for(i=999;i>99;i--) {
        for(j=999;j>99;j--) {
            number = i*j;
            revrse = 0;
            temp=number;
            while (temp != 0){
                revrse = revrse * 10;
                revrse = revrse + temp%10;
                temp = temp/10;
            }
            if(number == revrse) {
                if(number > maks) {
                    maks = number;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d",maks);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I was so confused why it wasn't working properly, that I misslooked intial. those 2 ints.

Answer (score 5):

The `revrse` var isn't initialized so there are rubbish in it. Remember to always init a variable!

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the answer from @kleszcz, `revrse` must always be initialized before the `while` loop begins, otherwise, it will hold the previous value (and rubbish in the first iteration, as he intelligently pointed out).

Another issue is that you do not need the `is_palindrome` function. You can check directly if the numbers are equal.